# How to insert jface TreeViewer in second or in particular column?

Tags: java, swt, jface, treeviewer

I am trying to insert jface TreeViewer in second column (task name) of my GUI but its incorporate with first column(task ID). So how can i get the control to shift this from one column to second column.

Comment: Which layout are you using?

Comment: I am using Grid layout

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this with `GridLayout` is to insert dummy `Label`s that take up the spaces "in front" of your `TreeViewer`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));

    /* Top row */
    new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button");
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

    /* Middle row */
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button");
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

    /* Bottom row */
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button");

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Produces this:

[image]